# Observable not working in two seperate component in Angular

Tags: angular, types, observable

I have `component A` which is `navigation bar` and `component B` which is `list view` where user details are shown.

> Navbar component :

```
 <select class="form-control"(change)="selectUsers($event)" [(ngModel)]="UserId">
           <option *ngFor="let opt of userlist" value={{opt.UserId}}>{{opt?.userName}}
 </option>
 </select>
```

On change of dropdown i call a method

```
 selectUsers(event) {
     this.CommonService.SelectedUserId = event.target.value;
     this.CommonService.updateSelecteduserDropdown(event.target.value);
     this.router.navigate(['/users-list']);
  }
```

> CommonService

```
 private globalDropdownData = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

 public getSelecteduserDropdown(): Observable<string> {
    return this.globalDropdownData .asObservable();  
  }
 
  public updateSelecteduserDropdown(value: string): void {
    this.globalDropdownData.next(value);
  }
```

In my component B in my constructor i have used this code

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
subGlobal: Subscription;
 constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef..)
 {
    this.subGlobal= this.CommonService.getSelecteduserDropdown().subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.datafetch();
        this.router.navigate(['/users-list']);
      }
    });
 }
 datafetch()
 {
   this.Userslist.....  Fetch  data
 }
```

> In view :

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of Userslist | paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ;"
..
..
</tbody>
```

What i want is to whenever the id changes it must fetch the new data in component B Table after dropdown change

Any Solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you add logs in your code ?
   Do you retrieve data here in your component B inside the subsciption ?
2. You should make you subscription inside the ngOnInit method.
3. Is your CommonService correctly declare in your component B ?
4. You call this method twice when you use the dropdown : `this.router.navigate(['/users-list']);`. Maybe, it is not usefull, or you can remove one.